# How can I use find to search for symbolic links?

Tags: bash, find, symlink

This is what I have:

```
abc:~/findtests$ ls -l  
total 0  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 abc abc 22 2010-11-30 14:32 link1 -> /home/abc/testpy1.py
```

I am trying to search for the link `link1` in the current directory.

I did :

```
abc:~/findtests$ find -L . -lname 'link1'
abc:~/findtests$ find -P . -lname 'link1'
abc:~/findtests$ find -L . -lname 'test*'
abc:~/findtests$ find -P . -lname 'test*'
```

But could not get any output. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, from the man page:

> "Using -L causes the -lname and -ilname  predicates  always  to return false."

The target of the symbolic link doesn't match 'test*' because there is the full path. Try '*/test*'.

Comment: Looks like I can't use -lname to find symlink via its name.

Comment: Yes, `-lname` looks at the target only. If you to look for the name of the symlink itself, just use `-type l -name`.

Answer (score 1):

How about `find . -type l -name link1`?

Also, `find . -lname '*test*'` seems to work for me.

Comment: This works. But I am interested in knowing what am I doing wrong above. I was reading the findutils manual and I am pretty sure I did what it said.

Comment: `-lname` matches against the target of the symbolic link, and your pattern was wrong.

Comment: I think the leading asterisk is the answer.

Comment: -L should not work unless the syslink is broken. -P is the default and should work.

Comment: @abc Point taken (the link was broken).

Answer (score 0):

"Using -L causes the -lname and -ilname predicates always to return false." says the find man page

so those two wouldn't work anyway

but is the problem to be solved to find a symlink via its target path or by its name as aix's answer does

Comment: The problem is to find symlink via its name. Can I not use -lname for that ?

Comment: `-lname` gets compared to the link's target path but as you state you want to find it by its directory entry name which `find . -type l -name link1` as aix said would do that